# How to modify openCV source code?

Tags: opencv

I copied the part of codes that I wanted to modify into my main.cpp.  However, upon executing it, the speed is much slower.  Why is that so and how do I modify codes in this case?

Comment: Can you give us examples? What functions are you trying to replace?

Answer (score 7):

Am not sure exactly what you are looking for but if you are trying to modify some bits of OpenCV source and use it in your code then here's a way of doing it:

```
-> modify the source code. for example `./src/cv/vcsurf.cpp` 
-> cd $(OPENCV_HOME)/src and run cmake CMakeLists.txt
-> make //if you have permission errors use sudo make
-> sudo make install
```

I usually customize OpenCV library this way for my programs
Let me know if you are looking for something completely different. And if anyone thinks this approach is bad please let me know, I'd be more than happy to learn.

Best.